# Array.some is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am attempting to pass 2 arrays to a function that filters through array 1 by array 2, then returns the filtered results.

I am not understanding why I am getting the error: "Uncaught TypeError: arr2.some is not a function"

Function Code:

```
function filterTF(arr1,arr2) 
{
    return arr1.filter(function(el) 
    {
        return arr2.some(function(e) 
        {
            return el.timeframe == e;
        });
    });
}
```

Array 1:

```
[
    {"time":"2016-11-30 02:45:00","signal":"Buy","symbol":"AUDNZDecn","price":"1.04605","timeframe":"M15","epoch":"1480473900","candel":"M151480481100"},{"time":"2016-11-30 02:41:00","signal":"Sell","symbol":"AUDJPYecn","price":"84.08700","timeframe":"M1","epoch":"1480473660","candel":"M11480480860"},{"time":"2016-11-30 02:24:59","signal":"Buy","symbol":"EURNZDecn","price":"1.48820","timeframe":"M5","epoch":"1480472699","candel":"M51480479900"}
]
```

Array 2:

```
5,15
```

Code that Runs the Function:

```
var timeframearr = localStorage.getItem("timeframe");

if(timeframearr.length === 0) 
{
    console.log("Wings - Timeframe Set: False");
    var timeframearr = [];
} 
else 
{
    var j = filterTF(j,timeframearr);
}
```

**Note:** j is equal to a JSON parsed server response from an AJAX query that talks to a php script, which passes back a JSON response, aka the array above. timeframearr is either created new if its length is equal to 0, or if it exists in local storage then it gets it from there.

Code that puts timeframearr in local storage:

```
if ($('#timeframe-checkbox1').is(":checked")) 
{
    var t1 = $('#timeframe-checkbox1').val();
    console.log($('#timeframe-checkbox1').val());
    timeframearr.push(t1);
}

if ($('#timeframe-checkbox2').is(":checked")) 
{
    var t2 = $('#timeframe-checkbox2').val();
    console.log($('#timeframe-checkbox2').val());
    timeframearr.push(t2);
}

if ($('#timeframe-checkbox3').is(":checked")) 
{
    var t3 =  $('#timeframe-checkbox3').val();
    console.log($('#timeframe-checkbox3').val());
    timeframearr.push(t3);
}

localStorage.setItem("timeframe", timeframearr);
```

**Goal:** What I am trying to accomplish/understand is how to do is filter by multiple "timeframe" values of the array at a time, so that when a user clicks a checkbox for a combination of any of the three timeframes, I can pull the value from the checkboxes and filter the array by whatever combination of checkboxes the user had selected. ex. "M1", "M5", "M15", "M1,M5" or M1,M15" or M5,M15" or "M1,M5,M15" and so on.

The new array that is returned/filtered will get passed to a jquery each loop, that will then go through the data and append the data to a div. (I have this part working already)

Appreciate any guidance!

Comment: ```5,15``` - did you mean ```[5,15]``` ? - Else, ```5,15``` is not an array... It's just a string.

Comment: Are you *sure* the JSON was parsed? Signs indicate that it wasn't.

Comment: tymeJV is right, if you get the value from localStorage you will have to split the string. .split(',')

Comment: I thought it was. But I will double check. Never hurts to double check.

Comment: nvm, tymeJV is right. `arr2` / local storage is the issue.

Comment: @tymeJV When I push the numbers into the array with the code you see, the local storage is showing 5,15 not 5,15. However if I manually change the localstorage value to [5,15], or ['5','15'] it still gives the same result.

Comment: @user3259138 -- See my answer below, it should solve your issues.

Comment: @tymeJV okay let me report back here shortly after I do some testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is your `localStorage` - this will convert your array to a string (comma separated). What you should do is `stringify` before setting `localStorage` and parse on the way out:

```
localStorage.setItem("timeframe", JSON.stringify(timeframearr));
```

And pull it out as an array

```
var arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("timeframe"));
```

Answer (score 6):

We had this pop up today and in our case we had someone passing an Input variable as a boolean where it was expected to be an array type. So a simple check was put in place before the .some line.

```
if (Array.isArray(myVar)) {
    // then do stuff
}
```